# Matching regular expression or leaving empty string when not found

Tags: python, regex

this is my first post on this site so tell me if I mess something up. I need to find config files for files of the same name, with the difference being config files have 'str' at the end of them.
`some characters + _digit + car + some more characters + str or nothing.`
All files are in text form, so extension doesn't give any more information. Included in file name are also some important information, like number of occurrence, which i need to extract as well.

My approach using regex boils down to this

```
import re

reg = '(.*(?=\\dcar))(\\d(?=car)).*(str)?'      

config_to_file1 = 'wts-lg-000191_0car_lp_str'
file1 = 'wts-lg-000191_0car_lp'

print(re.findall(reg,file1))
print(re.findall(reg,config_to_file1))
```

i also tried this

```
reg = '(.*(?=\\dcar))(\\d(?=car)).*(str)+'
```

I expected to get this:

```
[('wts-lg-000191_', '0', 'str')]
[('wts-lg-000191_', '0', '')]
```

But got this instead:

```
[('wts-lg-000191_', '0', '')]
[('wts-lg-000191_', '0', '')]
```

I know i don't use ? token properly, I tried looking around and I don't know what am i missing. I also want to stick with regular expression approach for practice purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason your regex fails is that `.*` before `(str)?` grabs the whole string to the end, and `(str)?` just matches the end of string position since it does not have to consume any chars (as it is optional).

However, your regex can be greatly optimized as you are overusing lookarounds. Use

```
reg = r'(.*?)(\d)car(?:.*(str))?'
```

Or

```
reg = r'(.*?)(\d+)car(?:.*(str))?'
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/p5MXU9) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/laUOQz/1).

**Details**

- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `car` - a `car` string
- `(?:.*(str))?` - an optional non-capturing group that matches 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `.*`  - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible
  - `(str)` - Group 3: `str` substring.

Comment: Thanks! that works as intended. I just discovered lookarounds today so i was playing around with them. I will accept your answer in 3 minutes. And thanks for explanation as to why it did't work, educational stuff!